# Add meta tag description, page title and abstract programatically

Tags: theming, meta-tags, 7

I have created a custom page using a tpl.php file and I want to add meta tag page title, abstract and description that page. Can anyone show me how to add these meta tags programatically to custom page?

```
$description = array(        
                 '#type' => 'html_tag',
                 '#tag' => 'meta',
                 '#attributes' => array(
                 'name' => 'description',
                 'content' => 'here all description goes',
               )
 );
drupal_add_html_head($description, 'description');
```

This is the code I am using to add description to my head.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your theme's template.php file, you could add something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html
 */
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  if (current_path() == 'my/custom/path') {
    $description = array(        
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'content' => 'here all description goes',
      )
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($description, 'description');
  }

}
```

Clear cache to register new preprocess function.